# Weird problem with my Laravel site's view file, How is this possible?

Tags: laravel

I checked out the codes of one of my Laravel website's view files this morning on the online server and noticed that they are not the same as what I was uploaded before and with my local backup files which contain my last updates! However, my website showing everything exactly what should be! (Matching with my last changes) I checked files multiple times but the result was the same and codes don't match! How is this possible?

Comment: are you using versioning control?

Comment: What is that anyway?

Comment: may be view file cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel caches the compiled views when the `APP_DEBUG=false` and the environment is production. so you can do two things

go to following path

> storage/framework/views

and delete all the compiled views.

or

```
php artisan view:clear
```

run from console

Comment: Deleted files in storage/framework/views and seems everything work fine now, Thank you

Comment: @EhsanMousavi glad it helped you.